# Python - Read specific sheet of XLSM book that contains 7 sheets with macros and formulas. Find string in cell, replace string. Write back to XLSM

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Issue: Pandas to_excel writing as .xslx instead of .xlsm. Need to maintain macros in books.

I have about 3000 xlsm files that are moderately complex with a few macros. There are about 7 sheets per book. I need to find a string(s) in a static column on a specific sheet and replace that string in all books.

The approach I am taking is using pandas with openpyxl. I use pandas to read in a dataframe from the specific sheet, check the specific column for my string, if found, replace and write to a new sheet. (At least for now. I'll be replacing the original sheet with the new dataframe as I can't write just one cell or I would do that, but this is my proof of concept for now). The issue I get is pandas' to_excel function writes the file as xlsx (it actually writes the filename as a .xlsm but it's corrupted, changing the ext to .xslx allows it to be opened). Any ideas on how to write a pandas dataframe to xlsm? Or go about this issue another way?

```
for file in sorted(files):
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
    df = pandas.read_excel(files[file], sheet_name='Planning')
    
    #get data from sheet
    string_found=False
    for comment in df['Comment'].values:
        try:
            if re.search('mystring', comment, re.IGNORECASE):
                string_found=True
                print(file, comment)
        except TypeError:
            pass #not a string

    #add new sheet. 
    if string_found:
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(files[file], keep_vba = True)
        with pandas.ExcelWriter(files[file], mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            writer.workbook = book
            writer.sheets.update(dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets))
            writer.vba_archive = book.vba_archive
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Planning2')
```

This does what I ask it to, just writes it as xlsx (with a .xlsm extension), losing the macros. Thoughts?

Comment: would you be able to produce a minimal file with the features you have there? (a xslm, multi-sheet (2 are enough), a macro and other features you need preserved), so that it is easier to would-be respondents to test if they have a working way?

Comment: If any respondent can get an xlsm as output (that opens!), I'd be happy to see their response.

Comment: If you just want to write to a single cell, you can use the package [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/datastructures.html)

Comment: It seems xlwings was built for interactive workflows, and only works on windows or mac. I'm on windows, but do all my development in vscode WSL. xlwings sees this as linux and won't work. Think it would just be easier to write a function in VBA rather than setting up a whole new windows python ecosystem to work with the xlwings package. Not to mention having a windows ecosystem and wsl ecosystem, with their own anaconda's, python distros etc... Just gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

I avoided using pandas df and used openpyxl to just change one cell at a time rather than trying to work within the df.

```
for file in sorted(files):    
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=files[file], read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["sheet1"]
#could update this section with a for c in range(1, ws.max_column+1) if we want to iterate through every column as well (replacing 5 with c)
i = 0
for r in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    s = ws.cell(r, 5).value
    if s in FIND_VAL:
        ws.cell(r, 5).value = REPLACE_VAL
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spire.XLS for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/Spire-XLS-Python.html) module can be used to replace string in XLSM files. You can install it using the following command:

```
pip install Spire.Xls
```

Here is an example:

```
import os
from spire.xls.common import *
from spire.xls import *

# Specify the path to the folder containing the XLSM files
folder_path = "Files/"

# Iterate through the files in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
    
    # Check if the file is an XLSM file
    if filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
        # Create a Workbook object
        workbook = Workbook()
        # Load the XLSM file
        workbook.LoadFromFile(file_path)

        # Get a specific sheet by its index
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]
        # Or get a specific sheet by its name
        # worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["SheetName"]

        # Find the cells containing a specific text in the worksheet
        ranges = worksheet.FindAll("text_to_find", FindType.Text, ExcelFindOptions.MatchEntireCellContent)

        # Iterate through the found cells
        for range in ranges:
            # Replace the text in the cell with another text
            range.Text = "replacement_text"
            # Set a highlight color for the cell
            range.Style.Color = Color.get_Yellow()

        # Save the result to a new XLSM file
        result_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "Result_" + filename)
        workbook.SaveToFile(result_file_path, FileFormat.Xlsm)
        workbook.Dispose()
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that developed this module.